# Execute powershell script on webserver when page is accessed

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have a windows 7 Pro computer that is running XAMPP (apache, php).
What I need to do is execute a batch or powershell command on this computer (host) when a remote computer accesses a certain webpage on it.  is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a PHP function that will execute shell code.
Have a look in their documentation
Function: exec("command here");